# How to Play Video in Unity 2D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

i need to play Videos in my 2d game. many Tutorials in Youtube how to play Videos but its 3d. so share with me how to play Video File in unity

- Video Format

Comment: What have you tried so far? Sharing any code or explaining the steps you've taken are good things to add to your question.

Comment: but I'm new in Unity so No Idea. so I don't have Code@BrianD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both 2D or UI layer, you can simply play video using MovieTexture.

For example, I assume you wanna play video on UI. So what you need to to is creating a RawImage on UI, then creating a MovieTexture with your movie as material. Finally, put the material in the RawImage.

More detail: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/940565/movietexture-in-ui-panel.html

Comment: Unity 5.6 is working on new VideoPlayer and VideoClip Api, here's a nice video tutorial explaining that https://youtu.be/nGA3jMBDjHk

Answer (score -2):

First of all if you are using Windows, install Quicktime and later drag and drop the movie file to your project view in Unity, it will import the file like a movie texture.

If you want to display the video in a 3d or 2d game, you can do this through the UI with a RawImage component, just set the Movie Texture as the Texture of the RawImage component in the inspector.

To control the video, you can do it with this simple script, you must attach it to the GameObject with the Raw Image component.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class VideoHandler : MonoBehaviour {
    RawImage raw;
    MovieTexture m;

    void Start () {
        raw = GetComponent<RawImage>();
        m = (MovieTexture)raw.mainTexture;
    }

    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {

            if (m.isPlaying)
            {
                m.Pause();
            }
            else
            {
                m.Play();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and you are done!